# ntohs() and ntohl() equivalent?

Tags: c#, htonl

Are there net to host conversion functions in C#? Googling and not finding much. :P

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[`IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.hosttonetworkorder.aspx) and [`IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.networktohostorder.aspx)?

Each method has overloads for 16, 32 and 64 bit integers.

Comment: I assume these 2 methods do the same thing. I note the overloads are only for signed things. Are they safe on unsigned things?

Comment: @pm100: You'd expect them to be self-inverses, yes. I wouldn't like to claim that for absolute fact though :) Not sure what you mean by "safe on unsigned things" - you'd have to cast first, at which point it wouldn't be unsigned...

Comment: first - given that a significant number of the things they work on will be things like IP addresses which are unsigned its surprising that there are no overloads for uint32 etc. By 'safe' I mean I am wary of casting signed to unsigned, fiddling with bits and casting back, in general this is a recipe for sign propagation / truncation ,... wiednesses

Comment: you should write which one is ntohs and which one is ntohl

Comment: @SSpoke: Both `ntohs` and `ntohl` would be `NetworkToHostOrder`, but with different overloads for the different sizes.

Comment: The method doesn't always work, and doesn't even tell you that it might fail. 
I was passing in a `uint` I got from a udp socket, and `NetworkToHostOrder` doesn't accept unsigned (since unsigned numbers are not CLS compliant), and silently converted them to `long`, which is obviously wrong. The solution is to use `BitConverter`.

Comment: @Leandros: It sounds like what you should do instead is just cast to `int`, and cast the result back to `uint`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, that works equally well, and is probably a little better, since it'll avoid the allocation of a temporary array.

Answer (score 5):

The [System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) nuget package includes the `System.Buffers.Binary.BinaryPrimitives` static class, which includes static methods for dealing with "endianness", including many overloads of `ReverseEndianness`. On dotnet core, `HostToNetWorkOrder` is implemented using these `ReverseEndianness` methods . On a little-endian architecture (which I think is all that support .NET) `HostToNetworkOrder` and `ReverseEndianness` methods have identical performance on dotnetcore.

On dotnet framework (net461) however, the performance of calling `HostToNetworkOrder` is slightly (not quite 2x) slower than calling `ReverseEndianness`.

I believe that the JIT compiler is actually special casing these methods to invoke the BSWAP x86 instruction. If you exactly duplicate the implementation of the `ReverseEndianness(long)` method in your own codebase, it will be nearly 4x slower than calling the `System.Memory` implementation; suggesting there is JIT magic happening.

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

[@jon-skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2420243/470091) is the most accurate according to your question. However, 'ntoh_' and 'hton_' C functions are extensively used in order to translate between [little-endian and big-endian computer architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

If your intention is **to perform endianess conversions**, there is a [**BitConverter class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.BitConverter.aspx) (static class in the core assembly) that brings you a more suitable way. Specially when:

- Working with array of bytes (widely used in file or network streams).
- [Detecting endianess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx) architecture of the runtime machine.
- Converting basic structures beyond integers (booleans, decimals) without typecasting.
- Your code is not related to network operations (System.Net namespace).

Comment: except that class doesnt have an equivalent function to htonl. I would have to get the bytes, reverse them, then convert back

Comment: `BitConverter` doesn't support any non-native endianness.  (At least the built-in one doesn't, Jon or Marc made a more powerful one that does -- but making garbage temporary arrays is still a waste)