# convert c/c++ macro into equivalent code in c#

Tags: c#, c++, c, macros

plz , i need help about how can i get the equivalent code in c# to any macro code in c/c++ as this macro .

```
#define BYTESWAP16(x)                   \
    ((((x) >> 8) & 0x00FF) | (((x) << 8) & 0xFF00))
#define BYTESWAP32(x)                   \
    ((((x) >> 24) & 0x000000FF) | (((x) >> 8) & 0x0000FF00) | \
     (((x) << 8) & 0x00FF0000) | (((x) << 24) & 0xFF000000))
#define ntohs(x)                        BYTESWAP16(x)
#define htons(x)                        BYTESWAP16(x)
#define ntohl(x)                        BYTESWAP32(x)
#define htonl(x)                        BYTESWAP32(x)
```

Comment: If C# doesn't supports macros then use pass by reference.

Comment: C# doesn't support macros.

Comment: One: Why use macros for this? there are functions. Second, this is a duplicate: [ntohs() and ntohl() equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420227/ntohs-and-ntohl-equivalent)

Comment: static uint BYTESWAP16(uint x)
        {
            return ((x >> 8) & 0x00FF) | ((x << 8) & 0xFF00);
        }

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.hosttonetworkorder.aspx) and [`IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.networktohostorder.aspx) to perform these operations.  These are built into the framework.

Answer (score 0):

You may define a sealed  abstract class with static methods that will do the same as your macros do.

Comment: Why not just a static class?

Comment: Reed Copsey, it could be if he is not going to inherit some interfaces.